# Why press button second times after Conditional Statements become false?

Tags: jquery

```js
$(function() {

  $("button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "3") {
      console.log("correct");
      $(this).text("correct")
    } else {
      console.log("worng");
      $(this).text("worng")
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="questionPage">
  <h1>Question</h1>
  <br>
  <p>1 + 2 = ?</p>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>6</button>
</div>
```

Why press button second times after conditional Statements become false ?

when press answer"3" button second times after.

button context show worng and console too.

that mean conditional Statements become false bool.

i hope several times press answer"3" button still show correct.

what method limit one click ? or several times  press button conditional still work ?

thanks.

Comment: because after you click the first time you set the text of the button to correct. Second click will compare "correct" to "3" and it will fail. If you do not update button text it will always be ok

Comment: so good way seem is  limit one click on correct answer button ?  but how ?

Comment: Add a disabled attribute to the button after the click. Or follow the data- attribute suggestions below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you add something like this: `<button data-answer="3">3</button>`

Then even when you change the text of the button it don't fail.

Also if you want to limit it to one click even, you could remove the click event from the button once it's been pressed with `$(this).off("click")` after your `if/else` statement

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {

  $("button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("data-answer") === "3") {
      console.log("correct");
      $(this).text("correct")
    } else {
      console.log("wrong");
      $(this).text("wrong")
    }
    $(this).off("click")
  })
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="questionPage">
  <h1>Question</h1>
  <br>
  <p>1 + 2 = ?</p>
  <button data-answer="3">3</button>
  <button data-answer="6">6</button>
</div>
```